# Wordpress contact form 7 template file

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/) plugin for my Wordpress and I'm wondering to which template it links when I type `mysite.com/contact/`. I want to edit the template file but don't know where to find it. Any advice much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Form 7 does not have a template file. Rather, it adds fields (defined in the admin) into your page via a shortcode.

You can override the default CF7 styles by editing your theme's **style.css** file.

Your contact page itself is likely using a [default or specialized WordPress page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

Comment: @mevius but when I only have one page with permalink `/contact-field` why is `/contact` redirecting to a page as well, thats what I'm wondering.